# Actualizar Combobox(DevExpress) en Form Principal al cerrar Form secuandario vb.net

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Buenas tardes colegas de la informatica recurro a su muy buena ayuda estoy trabajado con SQL 2012 Y VB 2015 con componente de devexpress tengo un problema y es el siguiente tengo dos formulario le pondremos form 1 y form 2
  lo que deseo es que lo que hago en el form 2 ya sea actualizar borrar o agregare elemento se me actualize en un combox que tnego en el form 1 lo intentado poniendo en el evento Activited del form 1 me lo hace bien pero me manda un error al iniciar el form 1 procedimiento para cargar ese combox me falta un parametro y esta claro por que el form1 esta en blanco como puedo hacer para evitar ese error

espero me aya dado a entender 
espero su  ayuda gracias

Answer (score 0):

YA  LO RESOLVI

LES COMPARTO COMO LO HICE

CREE UNA CLASE

Public class convo 
 IF String.NullOfEmpety(nombre del combox) then
exit sub
  End if
end class